# Orchard CMS - Edit link not working on Bootstrap Theme

Tags: module, twitter-bootstrap, themes, orchardcms, editing

I have enabled the Content Control Wrapper and Widget Control Wrapper.  The edit link appear fine in the default theme but doesn't appear with the Bootstrap 2.0.2 theme enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Find site.css in the Styles folder. The last line is this:

```
.manage-actions {display:none;}
```

That's what's making the links disappear. You can replace it with, for example:

```
.manage-actions {position:absolute;}
```